# Tabulator: how to start remote pagination on arbitrary page

Tags: tabulator

I've been quite pleased with how remote pagination on Tabulator works with automatic ajax loading, but I can't seem to find a way to set the page that is displayed when the table is first loaded.  `table.setPage(pageNum)` only works for me after the first page has been fetched and rendered; if I do something like

```
new Tabulator("#my-tabular-table", { lots of stuff }).setPage(5)
```

then I get a `Pagination Error - Requested page is out of range of 1 - 1:` because the page count hasn't been received from the server yet.

Is there some way of doing this? Am I missing something? I realize that I could hook into some callback and switch to the desired page immediately after the first page has been loaded, but I'd rather not wait for an extra server call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ***paginationInitialPage*** option in the table definition to set the page number for the initial load:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    pagination:"remote", //enable remote pagination.
    paginationInitialPage:2, // this option can take any positive integer value
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, not sure how I missed that option when looking at the documentation... Unfortunately though, and strangely enough, I get that same `Pagination Error - Requested page is out of range of 1 - 1: 2` when I set `paginationInitialPage:2`.

Comment: Just commenting for the benefit of anyone else who comes across this: I think the issue I describe in my comment above is due to a bug so I've filed an issue on github ( https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3101). If/when that gets resolved I can probably accept this answer.

Comment: That bug has now been resolved in the latest release :)